# Failing at Logging HTTP Requests for testing file download

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am trying to replicate this:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/

My target page has `target="_blank"` is there a way how to change the attribute removing this `target`?

So the test fails.

It is not very clear what the code in the example does. Does URL have to be of the page where the download link is present?

```
import { ClientFunction, t, Selector, RequestLogger } from 'testcafe'
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
...
const forInvoice = new ForInvoice()
const client = 'STRV s.r.o.'

const url = urlFor('?/timers/unbilledOverview')
const logger = RequestLogger({ url, method: 'post' }, {
logResponseHeaders: true,
logResponseBody:    true
});

fixture.only `For Invoicing`
   .requestHooks(logger);

test('Verify download of .xls and .pdf', async t => {
    await t.useRole(ADMIN_INVOICE)
    await forInvoice.navigateToForInvoicing()
    await forInvoice.filterClient(client)
    await t
        .click(Selector('a').filter('.sc-mini-icon-file.excel-file'))
        .expect(logger.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'STRV-s-r-o-Attachment');

    console.log(filePath);
    console.log(logger.requests[0].response.headers);

    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, logger.requests[0].response.body);

})
```

Comment: Could you please provide the text of the error thrown on your side?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that in the provided example, you did not specify the start page for the fixture or test. This might be the cause of the error.

The TestCafe example you mentioned does the following:

1. Creates a `RequestLogger` instance, which monitors requests (headers and body) to the same page on which the test starts.
2. Clicks the button to initiate the file download.
3. Waits for the server's success response.
4. Saves the response body to a file.

The `url` parameter in the filter object corresponds to the page to which the request is sent ([documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook.html#filter-by-parameters)) and doesn't have to match the tested page's URL.

You can modify an element on the page using [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) with the standard Web API. You can take the following code to get started:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe'

const link = Selector('a');

const removeTarget = ClientFunction(() => {
    link().removeAttribute('target');
}, { dependencies: { link } })

fixture`Fixture name`
    .page`https://your_page.com/`;

test('Remove target', async t => {
    await removeTarget();
});
```